# Router.express() -> What is the proper way for expressing router.use?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

For router.use, it does not work like this anymore:

```
router.use("/api", apiRoutes);
```

Instead an error is thrown: 
**throw new typeerror('router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))**

How do I re-purpose that expression so that it works? I have not found any examples that were useful so far. Here is some of my sample code:

routes/index.js (this does not work)

```
const path = require("path");
const router = require("express").Router();
const apiRoutes = require("./api");

// API Routes
router.use("/api", apiRoutes);**// this throws an error**
router.use(function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"));
 });

module.exports = router;
```

Here is an example of my attempt to re-purpose but I do not think it's correct:

```
var path = require("path");
var router = require("express").Router();
var apiRoutes = require("./api");

//API Routes
//authRouter.use(require('./authenticate').basic(usersdb))
//router.use("./api", apiRoutes);
console.log("Hitting API routes...")
router.use("./api", function(req, res, next) { **//re-purpsose attempt here**
   res.send(apiRoutes)
   console.log("API Routes:", apiRoutes)
   next()
});
console.log("API Routes hit")
// //If no API routes are hit, send the React app
//    router.use(function(req, res) {
//    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/public/index.html"));
//    });

module.exports = router
```

This is the overall error I'm getting (404 returned): 
GET /api/website_1_function_call/scrape 404 4.004 ms - 173

I know that this may be due to something else indirectly but I really am not sure about the router.use part.

I know for sure that the routes are not being hit properly and would like to fix.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is more code:

server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

var express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require("morgan");
//const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var db = require("./models")
var routes = require("./routes");
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
var path = require('path');
//Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger("dev"));
//Add routes, both API and view
app.use(routes);
//replaced with below:
//app.use(app.router);
//routes.initialize(app);

// //Connect to the Mongo DB 
// mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/kaibru");

var syncOptions = { force: false };
// If running a test, set syncOptions.force to true
// clearing the `testdb`
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    syncOptions.force = true;
};

// Starting the server, syncing our models ------------------------------------/
db.sequelize.sync(syncOptions).then(function() {
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
      console.log(
        "==>   Listening on port %s. Visit http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.",
        PORT,
        PORT
      );
    });
  });

// //Start the API server
// app.listen(PORT, function() {
//     console.log(` ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`);
// });
```

routes/index.js

```
var path = require("path");
var router = require("express").Router();
var apiRoutes = require("./api");

//API Routes
//authRouter.use(require('./authenticate').basic(usersdb))
//router.use("/api", apiRoutes);
console.log("Hitting API routes...")
router.use("/api", function(req, res, next) { // this is my re-purpose 
attempt
    apiRoutes
    console.log("API Routes:", apiRoutes)
//    next()
 }); // this is my r-purpose attempt
console.log("API Routes hit")
// //If no API routes are hit, send the React app
//    router.use(function(req, res) {
//    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/public/index.html"));
//    });

module.exports = router
```

routes/api/index.js

```
var router = require("express").Router();
require("./website_1");
var website_1Routes = require("./website_1_function_call");
//const userRoutes = require("./user");

//Website_1 routes
//http://localhost:3000/api/website_1_function_call/scrape

//authRouter.use(require('./authenticate').basic(usersdb))
//router.use("/website_1_function_call", website_1Routes);
//experimental use
 router.use("/website_1_function_call", function(req, res, next) { // this is my re-purpose attempt
     website_1Routes
     console.log("website_1Routes:", website_1Routes)
//     next()
 }); //this is my re-purpose attempt
//router.use("/user", userRoutes); 

module.exports = router
```

routes/api/website_1_function_call.js

```
require("./website_1");
require("./website_1_db");
require("./website_1_router");

//Call scrape functions from website_1 file
mainscrape();

//specificScrape() //let's leave this one dormant for now

//Now for saving to database
saveToDatabase();

//Now for the routes
routing();
```

I think my re-purpose attempt worked ( I removed next() since there are no defined routes right after). It seems to be processing. However, now my response hangs and this happens:

```
GET /api/website_1_function_call/scrape - - ms - -
```

This prints in the browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/website_1_function_call/scrape 
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

0.chunk.js:871 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (0.chunk.js:871)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (0.chunk.js:366)
```

So now I think my scraper code and my code to update the database does not work.

Scrape function code:

```
//var express = require("express");
var router = require("express").Router();
require("../../controllers/website_1controller");
//requiring this website's models
var Items_1 = require("../../models/website_1");
//require("./website_1_db");
//require("./website_1_router");

// Our scraping tools
// Axios is a promised-based http library, similar to jQuery's Ajax method
// It works on the client and on the server

var axios = require("axios");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

mainscrape = function()  {
//Now to configure the routes
router.get("/scrape", function(req, res) {
//instead of simple res.render, user router.get  
console.log("scraping started...");
//Grab the html body with axios    
axios.get("url placeholder").then(function(response) {
//Load to cheerio and save to $ selector
    console.log("Scraping all greenheartshop mainpage...");
    var $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    var output = [];
    var promises = [];

//Now we need to grab the title reference for each article
$("article").each(function(i, element) {

//save empty result object
var result = {};

//thumbnail
result.thumbnail = $(this)
//.children("article.product-grid-item.product-block").html()
.children("figure.product-item-thumbnail")
.children("a")
.attr("href")
//console.log("result thumbnail")
//console.log(result)
console.log(result.thumbnail)

var result = {}
//details
result.detail= $(this)
//.children("product-item-mask").html()
.children("div.product-item-details")
// .children("div.product-item-brand")
// .children("h5.product-item-title")
// .children("a")
// .children("div.product-item-price")
//.children("product-price-line")
//.children("price-value")
.text()
//result.detail = result.detail.trim();
//console.log("result detail")
//console.log(result)
console.log(result.detail)

//Capture the scraped data and save to database
console.log("Capturing Scrape")
if(result.detail !== '') {
    var promise = Items_1
    .saveToDatabase(result, result, {upsert:true, new:true})
    console.log("saveToDatabase");
    promises.push(promise);
}
Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
    res.json(data);
});
//saveToDatabase();

// if (result.thumbnail !== {} && result.detail !== "") {
//     var promise = Items_1
//     // .items_1_create({
//     //     resultThumbnail: result.thumbnail,
//     //     resultDetails: result.detail  
//     //   })
//     promises.push(promise)
//     // .then(dbModel => output.push(dbModel));
//     Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
//       res.json(data)
//     })
//   }


});
});
//Now to CREATE the results using controller file
// console.log("creating items in the database now...")
// router.post('/scrape', website_1Controller.items_1_create);
//Now to display the results
// console.log("Items now being displayed...")
// router.get('/scrape/display', website_1Controller.items_1_list)
});
}
module.exports = router;
module.exports = mainscrape;
module.exports = specificScrape;
```

Code to update the database:

```
require("../../controllers/website_1controller");
require("./website_1");
var Items_1 = require( "../../models");

//After scraping the main page, the following function is to save to the 
database

saveToDatabase = function() {
    //prepare the data
    var result = {}
    var dataToStore = Items_1.items_1_create
    console.log(dataToStore)
    //console.log(items_1_create)
    //insert data to the database
    // dataToStore.save().// We will not sue this part for now
    //     then(() => {
    //         console.log("Data successfully saved");
    //     }).catch(err => {
    //         console.log("Error: ", err);
    //     });
}

module.exports = saveToDatabase;
```

Code for final routing (after scrape is complete)

```
var website_1Controller = require("../../controllers/website_1controller");
var router = require("express").Router();

routing = function() {
//Now to CREATE the results using controller file
 console.log("creating items in the database now...")
 //router.route("/browse")
 router.post('/browse', website_1Controller.items_1_create);
 router.get('/browse', website_1Controller.items_1_list);

//Now to display the results
 console.log("Items now being displayed...")
 //router.route("/browse:search")
 router.get('/:search', website_1Controller.items_1_specific);
};
require("./website_1");
module.exports = routing;
module.exports = router;
```

models

```
'use strict';
// Dependencies
// =============================================================

// Sequelize (capital) references the standard library
//var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
// sequelize (lowercase) references our connection to the DB.
//var sequelize = require("../config/connection.js");
// Creates a "Items_1" model that matches up with DB
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Items_1 = sequelize.define("Items_1", {
  // the routeName gets saved as a string
  detail: DataTypes.STRING,
  // the name of the character (a string)
  thumbnail: DataTypes.BLOB,
  // the character's role (a string)
  //role: Sequelize.STRING,
  // the character's age (a string)
  //age: Sequelize.INTEGER,

  // and the character's force points (an int)
  //forcePoints: Sequelize.INTEGER
}, {
  // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will 
   automatically
  // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into 
   plural.
  // if you don't want that, set the following
  freezeTableName: true
});

return Items_1;
//Syncs with DB
//Items_1.sync();

// Makes the Items_1 Model available for other files (will also create a table)
};
```

controller

```
// *********************************************************************************
// website_1controllers.js - this file offers a set of routes for displaying and saving data to the db
// *********************************************************************************

// Dependencies
// =============================================================
var db = require("../models");

//display results for mainpage scrape
exports.items_1_create = function(req, res) {

      db.Items_1.findOneAndUpdate(req.body, req.body, {upsert: true, new: 
       true})
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err))
      console.log("findOneAndUpdate complete")
 },

 exports.items_1_list = function(req,res) {
   db.Items_1.findAll({})
 },

 exports.items_1_specific = function(req,res) {
   db.Items_1.findById(req.params.search)
 },

function(err, results) {
  if (err) { return next(err); } //Error in API usage.
  if (results.result.thumbnail==={} && results.result.detail==="") {//No 
     Results.
    var err = new Error('Results not found');
    err.status = 404;
    return next(err)
  }
  //Successful, so render
  res.render("click_results", { title: 'Click Results', resultThumbnail: 
  result.thumbnail, resultDetails: result.detail });

}
```

So the new issue is that the response hangs. I think it's because the code to update the database does not work (using sequelize). Let me know if anything else is needed and thank you in advance.

Comment: router.use("./api",.. has a [dot], remove it

Comment: @mehta-rohan Thank you, I missed that. But I still get the 404. I'm not sure how to handle the "apiRoutes" object for example, in that same function...it's supposed to hit another route file and then continue on to call a function... The old way worked before... but now I just don't know how to re-purpose it to get what I want...

Comment: share the code of that file

Comment: @mehta-rohan I appreciate the help. I added the rest but let me know if you need anything else. I removed next() in the router.use part because I don't have any defined routes coming right after.

Comment: I would recommend having a look at https://github.com/anandundavia/express-api-structure -- I am the author

Comment: @AnandUndavia Thank you, I see some similarity especially in the routes.. Will have a better/deeper look later today

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the input everyone.  After reviewing I found out that the function itself does not have to be re-purposed as I initially thought... I didn't know that if, for example, you are using "router.use("/directoy", directory)  and you are using it in succession to point to different directories, the final directory hit must have a defined route like router.get(). I modularized my code to the point where the final directory was just a list of functions  (one of these functions had the router.get method). This did not work. When I point the file directly to the code containing the router.get method, my scraped data returns to the terminal. Just thought I'd share my findings at least because I didn't know this at all . Many thanks to @mehta-rohan and @Anand Undavia for the insights. I'm still trying to get the data to render to the page but that's a different problem altogether.